# When I scrape data from a website it only returns a newline

Tags: python, html

I've tried the code with different websites and elements, but nothing was working.

```py
import requests
from lxml import html 
page = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/username.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
follow = tree.xpath('//span[@class="g47SY"]/text()')
print(follow)
input()
```

Above is the code I tried to use to aquire the number of instagram followers someone had.

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems>?

Comment: Web scraping can be an interesting challenge. The key here is to learn how to use your debugger, so you can step through the code and explore the data as you go. What editor/IDE are you using? I recommend PyCharm. The community edition is free, and it has both a great integrated debugger and a Python console that you can open when you hit a breakpoint. This makes it super easy to try things out and figure out what you need to do next. I will be happy to advise on any of the details of how to use the debugger and Python console.

Comment: The URL you gave leads to a "Page Not Found".

Comment: @DanielWalker its a template username page as to hide personal information

Comment: I don't think .html is needed.

Comment: @MichaelGeary yeah i use IDLE for python so that'd make sense

Comment: First you could save all HTML in file and open it in web browser to see what you get. This page can use `JavaScript` to display elements and using `requests`/`lxml`/`beautifulsoup` can be useless because they can't run `JavaScript`. It may need also to logging. Server my have also complex system to recognize bots/spamers and it may send you warnigng or captcha instead of expected data.

Comment: Yeah, IDLE is nice and has a good debugger. You might try PyCharm as it is also free (for the community edition) and has an even better debugger plus the Python console where you can try out code snippets while stopped at a breakpoint. Give a shout if I can assist with any debugging tips! Also, @furas's comment may be very relevant here - many websites take measures to avoid letting you scrape the data.

Comment: you could use real URL in question - and then we all would test the same page to see the same problems. On same servers different pages may use different classes to stop spamers/bots - and then the same code may works for one person but not work for other person which use different URL on the same server.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with web scraping Instagram is that a lot of content, including tag attribute values, is rendered dynamically. So the class you are using to fetch followers may change.

If you are able to use the [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library in Python, you might have an easier time parsing the page and getting the data. You can install it using `pip install bs4`. You can then search for the `og:description` descriptor, which follows the Open Graph protocol, and parse it to get follower counts.

Here's an example script that should get the follower count for a particular user:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = 'google'
html = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + username)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
item = bs.select_one("meta[property='og:description']")
name = item.find_previous_sibling().get("content").split("•")[0]
follower_count = item.get("content").split(",")[0]
print(follower_count)
```

Comment: Thanks; this really helps!